# With optimized js enabled, my javascript code not working

Tags: 6, javascript

I have a drop down list. On the change event of the drop down list I have written some javascript code. When I select an option from the drop down list a site opens in the new window.

So for this I wrote some javascript code on the change event of the drop down list.

But the problem is that when I enable the optimize js files then my drop down change event does not work and when I disable the optimize js files then the change event of the drop down works.

So what should I do for this to work in both condition?

**UPDATED:**

```
Drupal.behaviors.change = function (context) {


    $(".test").change(function(){
        var page = $(".test").val();
        window.open(''+page+'', '_blank');
    }) ;

};
```

Comment: Is it a Jquery script?

Comment: yes, it is a jquery script.

Comment: Can you look into the error console `Ctrl + Shift + J` and post the errors ? If its an error like $ is not defined then its because Jquery Library is loaded after your scripts are loaded as said by ninjascorner

Comment: It might be helpful to post your JavaScript.

Comment: I have posted my javascript.

Comment: Is this D6 or D7 - if it's D7 then I'm pretty sure the `Drupal.behaviors` implementation is *slightly* wrong.

Comment: I am working in Drupal 6

Comment: I have done it by putting the js code inline using drupal_add_js() function, but it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason maybe is your custom script loads first before the Jquery script.

Try this:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() { 
    //your script here
  });
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
Drupal.behaviors.somethingHere = function (context) {
  //your script here
}
```

Comment: It may also be cache problem. Try to flush the cache and see what happens?

Comment: I tried both of your methods but it also did not work. See my question again, I have updated it with  my js code.

Comment: How/where did you add the script?

Comment: direct in the module file using `drupal_add_js("js_code", "inline", "footer", FALSE, FALSE);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but when you concatenate Javascript files, the problem could actually be from another file and not the one that isn't working.  I would try using

```
;Drupal.behaviors.change = function (context) {
    $(".test").change(function(){
        var page = $(".test").val();
        window.open(''+page+'', '_blank');
    }) ;
};
```

Note the semicolon at the beginning.  If the previous file is missing a semi-colon, it may work on its own, but result in a syntax error when you concatenate.  Out of habit, everything I declare at the top-level gets these.

Comment: did not work :(